# How to determine which biometric to use while using in Biometric Prompt?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-biometric-prompt

eg If user's phone has got both faceID as well as fingerprint.

Currently Biometric prompt is selecting one user has setup first

Comment: Unfortunately the API currently does not support this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[This blog post](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/migrating-from-fingerprintmanager-to-biometricprompt-4bc5f570dccd), explains how the Biometric implementations distinguish between **Strong vs Weak** biometrics. It mentions that your code doesn't determine whether biometric is Strong or Weak -- rather the OEM implementation does. Nonetheless, you can decide whether your app always use Strong biometric authentication. And the way to do that is to pass in a `CryptoObject` when you call `authenticate`.

- If you don't pass a `CryptoObject`, the system will choose for you.
- If you pass a `CryptoObect` to `authenticate()` then the system will use the strong sensor for your app.

Beyond this, you the developer doesn't decide which form factor is used to authenticate your users.

P.S. You may also find the [following blog post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/10/one-biometric-api-over-all-android.html) useful.